# How to make text split in two lines if it overflows from my uploaded image in php

Tags: php, html, image, text

I am uploading an image from my system and then writing text over it by merging it with a transparent image on which text is written. but if my string is too long den it is overflowing from my uploaded image. How can I split it from where it overflows??

1. index.php

   ```
   <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <h3>Select image to upload:<br></h3>
   <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*">
   <br><br>
   <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Enter your text">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
   </form>
   ```
2. test.php

   ```
   <?php
   $target_dir = "uploads/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
   if($check !== false) {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
   $uploadOk = 1;
   } else {
   $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   }
   $im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 400);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0 , 0, 0);
   $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

   imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
   imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 15, 15, $white, $_POST['font'], $_POST['text']);

   switch ($check['mime']){

       case "image/gif":
           header('Content-type: image/gif');

           $dest=imagecreatefromgif($target_file);

           imagealphablending($dest, false);
           imagesavealpha($dest, true);

           imagecopymerge($dest, $im, 15, 15, 0, 0, 400, 400, 100);

           imagegif($dest);

           imagedestroy($dest);
           imagedestroy($im);
           break;

       case "image/jpeg":
           header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
           $dest=imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
           imagealphablending($dest, false);
           imagesavealpha($dest, true);
           imagecopymerge($dest, $im, 15, 15, 0, 0, 400, 400, 100);
           imagejpeg($dest);
           imagedestroy($dest);
           imagedestroy($im);
           break;

        case "image/png":
           header("Content-type: image/png");
           $dest=imagecreatefrompng($target_file);
           imagealphablending($dest, false);
           imagesavealpha($dest, true);
           imagecopymerge($dest, $im, 15, 15, 0, 0, 400, 400, 100);
           imagepng($dest);                
           imagedestroy($dest);
           imagedestroy($im);
           break;
   }
    ?>
   ```

Comment: are your pictures having a certain width? or they change accordingly?

Comment: @Sina width and height vary from picture to picture.